# NSTreeController is not setting Core Data children attributes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

My NSTreeController is setting Core Data parent attributes but not children attributes.

I have a Core Data model like this

```
Item
    title (string)
    isLeaf (boolean,readonly)
    parent -> Group (inverse children)

Group (parent entity Item)
    children -> Item (inverse parent)

Leaf (parent entity Item)
```

I am then displaying it with NSOutlineView and using an NSTreeController. I use the method -[NSTreeController insertObject:atArrangedObjectIndexPath:] to try to insert Leaf's, the leafs parent property is set correctly but the parent Group.children property remains set to nil.

When I run the project I get the following warning on the console

```
Warning: <NSTreeController: 0x7fcd93c19d20>[object class: NSMutableDictionary] childrenKeyPath cannot be nil. To eliminate this log message, set the childrenKeyPath attribute in Interface Builder
```

even though childrenKeyPath is set in interface builder and why is it using NSMutableDictionary when I have a NSManagedObject subclasses SavedItem, SavedGroup and SavedLeaf. I have downloaded a couple of examples but I can not see what they are doing that I am not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for others, is I was trying to be clever and instead of defining the *isLeaf* property in the actual core data definition. I was try to hard code it in the implementation as returning *true* or *false* depending on whether it was *Group* or *Leaf*, for some reason **NSTreeController** does not like this, even if you also define it in the base class. I have overridden the **awakeFromInsert** method and set it there.

Also of interest is that **NSTreeController** also does not like it if you define the *children* property in the base class to do nothing/return *nil* (ie so the the *Group* subclass can override it), *children* entities will be saved but they will no be displayed. This is something I did in trying to solve my initial problem, I thought it was something people might like to know.